# X++ Compute columns

Tags: axapta, x++, aot

I try recreate SQL view in AOT and I need add compute column which reference view (FISCALCALENDARFLATTENEDVIEW). In the class I cannot retrieved fields for this view. Problem is with "sGREGORIANDATE = " line where I specify a fieldStr(), cannot do it for View. I put SQL statement just to help understand what I try achieve.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_DimFiscalPeriod] AS 
SELECT 
T1.RECID AS LEDGERRECID, 
T1.PARTITION AS PARTITION, 
T1.RECID AS RECID, 
T2.CALENDARID AS CALENDARID, 
T2.CALENDARRECID AS CALENDARRECID, 
T2.GREGORIANDATE AS GREGORIANDATE, 
T2.MONTH AS MONTH, 
T2.PERIODNAME AS PERIODNAME, 
T2.PERIODOFFSET AS PERIODOFFSET, 
T2.PERIODRECID AS PERIODRECID, 
T2.QUARTER AS QUARTER, 
T2.QUARTEROFFSET AS QUARTEROFFSET, 
T2.YEARNAME AS YEARNAME, 
T2.YEAROFFSET AS YEAROFFSET, 
T2.PARTITION AS PARTITION#2, 
(CAST ((((T1.RECID) * (100000)) + (DateDiff(d, {ts '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'}, T2.GREGORIANDATE))) AS NVARCHAR(50))) AS LEDGERGREGORIANDATEID 
FROM AXDB.dbo.LEDGER T1 
INNER JOIN 
AXDB.dbo.FISCALCALENDARFLATTENEDVIEW T2 
ON T1.FISCALCALENDAR  =  T2.CALENDARRECID
AND T1.PARTITION  =  T2.PARTITION
```

I created class but for my calculation need fields from both objects and column list for a view is not supported. sRECID is ok but sGREGORIANDATE definition is not.

```
public class vw_DimFiscalPeriod extends common
{
private static server str GregoriandDateID()
{
    str sReturn,
    str sRECID,
    str sGREGORIANDATE;
    DictView dictView;

    dictView = new DictView(tableNum(vw_DimFiscalPeriod));
    sRECID = dictView.computedColumnString(tableStr(Ledger), fieldStr(RecId),FieldNameGenerationMode::FieldList,  true);
    sGREGORIANDATE = dictView.computedColumnString(viewstr(FiscalCalendarFlattenedView),  fieldStr(GregorinaDate), FieldNameGenerationMode::FieldList,  true);

    sReturn = "("+RECID+" * 100000) + DateDiff(d, {ts '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'}, " + sGREGORIANDATE + " )";

     return sReturn;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work and line for sGREGORIANDATE should looks like that:

```
        sGREGORIANDATE = SysComputedColumn::returnField(tableStr(FiscalPeriodDateView), tableStr(FiscalCalendarFlattenedView), fieldStr(FiscalCalendarFlattenedView, GregorianDate)));
```